# How to fix Linking Error; SoundCloud iOS API

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am writing an iOS app that uses the soundcloud API. When I try to build a barebones project, I receive a linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCSoundCloud", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SoundCloudPlumbing.o

I followed all setup steps on https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#installation starting from "Install SDK and Dependencies" through to "Authentication." Then I created an objective-c file SoundCloudPlumbing.m with the following code (clientID, secret, and projectName changes for privacy reasons)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SoundCloudAPI/SCAPI.h>


void initializeSoundCloud(){
    [SCSoundCloud setClientID:@"heresAClientID"
                       secret:@"heresASecret"
                  redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ProjectName://oauth"]];
}
```

I have tried creating a new app and refollowing the setup instructions. I get the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the sound cloud framework or library to your project.

Comment: Did you determine a way through this?